# How to display products from a specific category on product view page in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, category-products

What I tried to archive is: Display a product list in a slider on product view page. The product list is from another category and all products in this list are not related to any other products.
I have tried so far:

> catalog.xml

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="cms/block" name="block_accessories_list">
  <action method="setBlockId">
      <block_id>block_accessories_list</block_id>
  </action>
</block>
</reference>
```

> template/catalog/product/widget/new/content/accessories.phtml

```
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && 

$_products->getSize()): ?>
<?php
  $_productCollection = $this->getItems();
  $theme = $this->helper('ultimo');
  $helpImg = $this->helper('infortis/image');
  $i = 0;
  $sliderClasses = '';
  $gridClasses = '';

  //Additional parameters
  $isResponsive = true;
  if ($_collectionSize <= $productCountInSlide)
  {
      //If total number of products is smaller than number of products displayed in a single slide
      $isResponsive = false;
  }
  //Slider parameters
  //--------------------------------------------------------------

  $sliderId = "itemslider-related-multi";

  //Responsive mode on/off
  $isResponsive = true;

  //Assign number of items in a row to specific viewport width
  $breakpoints = '[0, 1], [480, 2], [768, 4]';

  //Pagination on/off
  $pagination = false;

  //Slider timeout. Set to enable automatic scrolling.
  $timeout = intval($theme->getCfg('product_page/related_timeout'));

  //Number of items that should move on scrolling
  $move = 0;

  //If set, slider will loop
  $loop = $theme->getCfg('product_slider/loop');

  //Speed (arrows / touch swipe)
  $speed = intval($theme->getCfg('product_slider/speed'));

  //Speed (automatic scrolling / pagination)
  $autoSpeed = intval($theme->getCfg('product_slider/auto_speed'));

  //Pause slider on mouse hover
  $pause = $theme->getCfg('product_slider/pause');
?>
<div class="widget widget-new-products">
    <div class="widget-title">
        <h2><?php echo $this->__('') ?></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="widget-products">
    <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <div class="itemslider-wrapper itemslider-related-wrapper slider-arrows1 slider-arrows1-pos-top-right slider-pagination1">
    <?php if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
    <ul id="<?php echo $sliderId; ?>" class="itemslider <?php if($sliderClasses) echo $sliderClasses; ?> extra-product-slider">
    <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>

            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a class="product-link"
                href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
                title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                <div class="product-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize() ?>)">

                </div>
                  <div class="product-info-box">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
                      <h3 class="product-name"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name') ?></h3>
                      <p>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-widget-new-grid') ?>
                      </p>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==count($_products)): ?>
        </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    jQuery(function($) {

        var owl = $('#<?php echo $sliderId; ?>');
        owl.owlCarousel({

        <?php if(!$isResponsive): ?>
            responsive: false,
            items: <?php echo $showItems; ?>,
        <?php else: ?>
            itemsCustom: [ <?php echo $breakpoints; ?> ],
            responsiveRefreshRate: 50,
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($speed): ?>
            slideSpeed: <?php echo $speed; ?>,
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($autoSpeed): ?>
            paginationSpeed: <?php echo $autoSpeed; ?>,
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($move !== 1): ?>
            scrollPerPage: true,
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($timeout): ?>
            autoPlay: false<?php //echo $timeout; ?>,
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($pause): ?>
            stopOnHover: true,
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($loop): ?>
            rewindNav: true,
            rewindSpeed: 1000,
        <?php else: ?>
            rewindNav: false,
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($pagination): ?>
            pagination: true,
        <?php else: ?>
            pagination: false,
        <?php endif; ?>

            navigation: true,
            navigationText: false

        }); //end: owl

    });
//]]>
</script>
```

This code shows the latest added products from all categories. How do i change it, so it only display new products from one specific category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution by myself. I added this code at the top of accessories.phtml.

```
$categoryId = 10; 
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);


$collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image', 'price'));
```

And replace

```
if (($_products = $getProductCollection) && $_products->getSize()):
```

with

```
if (($_products = $collection) && $_products->getSize()):
```